# android animate activity switching

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, scale

I need to start activity B from activity A. Activity B must be started with an ScaleAnimation from certain coordinates. Usually, switching activities with animation is done by

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim1, R.anim.anim2);
```

but the position from where my activity "rise" is known only at runtime. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your animation then programmatically instead of using the XML. You can check more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've read this many times but method which is used to make the switch between activities with animations accept two int parameters, not two animation objects and I can not set an id to the animation at runtime